# UWP. Хранение интерфейса в БД и его динамическая загрузка во время выполнения, как?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, мобильная-разработка, uwp

Возможно ли реализовать хранение xaml в БД и построение интерфейса во время работы приложения в Windows Universal app? Например, у разных пользователей, в зависимости от прав, отобразить разные контролы с их привязкой к разным данным. Куда копать или что почитать?
предполагается, что пользователи будут создавать контент и интерфейс под него, с предоставлением доступа другим пользователям. поэтому и нужно будет хранить в БД.

Comment: ужасная идея. будет очень медленно.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь строить XAML, который вы собираетесь засовывать в БД?

Comment: Просто я новичок в этом вопросе, только начинаю осваивать разработку под WP. Пока прикидываю как реализовать. Уперся в невозможность обрабатывать XAML на лету. Т.е. пользователь в приложении выбрал элементы интерфейса и обработчики из списка, типа конструктора. А другие пользователи загружают этот интерфейс себе по желанию и используют.Наверное слишком замахнулся))

Comment: в таких случаях - разные контрол клепайте, селектора добавляйте и так далее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как создать элемент с XAML-кода на лету.

```
UIElement createElement(string xaml)
{
    // не забываем указывать xmlns в XAML-коде:
    // xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as UIElement;
}
```

Крайне **не рекомендую** такой подход. Это можно использовать лишь в крайних случаях.

Вряд ли пользователи Вашего приложения будут создавать в приложении какой-либо XAML-код вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Проще наделать заранее несколько разных `UserControl` и, как вы хотите, в зависимости от разных прав отображать на `Page` в `ContentControl` ту или иную юзерконтрол. Только упаси вас боже от подгрузки элементов интерфейса из БД!